# SpringIntegration remove message from the Queue without processing

Tags: java, spring, queue, jms, spring-integration

We have a **JMS** shutdown queue in our application, needed to shutdown running nodes with Spring context on specific events.

In order to properly shutdown running **ApplicationContext** without processing this "shutdown" message again on startup, we need to have a separate killing **Thread**, to be sure that message was processed before we kill **ApplicationContext**.

Is there a way to avoid additional killing **Thread**?

**For example:** Configure **SpringIntegration** flow to mark message read, right after reading it from the **Queue**, ignoring it's possible processing failure.

Comment: do you mean removing it from the queue without the risk of transactional rollback?  you can create your own instance of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and set `sessionTransacted` to `false` in the `jms:message-driven-channel-adapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you route the kill message to an `ExecutorChannel` (or `QueueChannel`), the message will be handed off to another thread, and the transaction will commit immediately.